# Is it possible to convert a long sound file to mono on Praat?

Tags: praat

My sound files are stereo sounds and I want convert them to mono sounds to remove one of the two channels on the screen, since they look identical. Since they are too long, I have to open them using the long sound option (otherwise the program is too slow). However, I do not find the option to convert a long sound file to mono. Is this possible at all? Thank you!

Comment: Not an answer, so I'm leaving this as a comment instead, but for me Praat tends to lag badly when importing and exporting long sounds; I'd convert to mono with ffmpeg or something else instead, and only import to Praat afterward.

Answer (score 2):

You can save a channel as WAV, AIFF, etc then re-open the single-channel file.

Answer (score 1):

You can open your file using Open > Read seperate channels from sound file. Then, save the channel you want.